# How do I use exceptions and promise rejections together in node.js?

Tags: node.js, exception, promise

In **node.js**, is there a good explanation of how exceptions work in conjunction with 'rejection' of promises?

Comment: That 'duplicate' is not a good explanation of how exceptions work in conjunction with rejection of promises. And it's marked as an opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Promise rejection is the asynchronous analogue to exceptions in synchronous code. An exception thrown inside a promise handler (be it in `then()`, `catch()` or `finally()`) is automatically converted to a promise rejection.

However, the opposite is not true. If you create a promise, or call a function that returns a promise that will ultimately be rejected, within a `try/catch` block there is no automatic conversion to an exception. But you can do it using `async/await`. This will work:

```
async function() {
    try {
        await getPromiseThatWillBeRejected();
    }
    catch (e) {
        // error that caused rejection can be handled here
    }
}
```

The `await` keyword virtually converts this to a synchronous blocking call (it is not really blocking but subsequent code is only executed after the promise is fulfilled or rejected) and converts the rejection to a synchronous exception.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a walkthrough of the combinations of exceptions and promise rejections.

Let's start with a promise that throws an exception, and another that completes the promise with a rejection, to compare them.

```
function thrower() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { throw new Error('thrown'); });
}

function rejecter() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject('rejected'));
}
```

The following calling code will receive the error in the same way:

```
thrower.catch(ex => console.log('caught ' + ex));
rejecter.catch(ex => console.log('caught ' + ex));
```

The result is `caught Error: thrown` and `caught rejected`. An exception reaching the `catch` function is straight forward. But it is strange that a rejected promise ends up in a `catch` function too. That's how it is, let's move on.

Similarly, an exception becomes a rejection. The following uses the second parameter of `then` to provide an `onrejection` function:

```
thrower().then(() => {}, err => console.log('err ' + err));
rejecter().then(() => {}, err => console.log('err ' + err));
```

Result is `err Error: thrown` and `err rejected`. Again, this makes sense, rejections reach the `onrejection` handler. It's a stretch, but meh sure, that exceptions land there too.

Now what if both `onrejection` handler and `catch` are used?

```
thrower().then(() => {}, err => console.log('err ' + err)).catch(ex => console.log('caught ' + ex));
rejecter().then(() => {}, err => console.log('err ' + err)).catch(ex => console.log('caught ' + ex));
```

The outcome is `err Error: thrown` and `err rejected`. Here it is somewhat confusing. The language routes the exception into the `err` function, and not to the `catch` function.

An important point, this code does not catch the exception:

```
try {
  thrower();
}
catch(ex) {
  console.log('caught ' + ex); // won't catch thrower's exception
}
```

Why of course - the `try/catch` block execution completes before the promise is executed.

But it is less obvious that this doesn't work either:

```
function throwerThrower() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { thrower().catch(ex => { throw ex }); });
}

throwerThrower().catch(ex => console.log('caught ' + ex));  // not going to catch nested throw
```

Cascading an exception like above will result in an unhandled exception.

However this next block does work and maybe shows how valuable it is to reject instead of throw:

```
function throwerRejecter() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { thrower().catch(ex => reject(ex)); });
}
throwerRejecter().catch(ex => console.log('caught ' + ex));
```

Finally, here are the last two nested combinations:

```
function rejecterThrower() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { rejecter().catch(ex => { throw ex }); });
}
rejecterThrower().catch(ex => console.log('caught ' + ex));
```

Returns `ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION` and that looks sensible as rejection handling threw an exception.

And

```
function rejecterRejecter() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { rejecter().catch(ex => reject(ex)); });
}
rejecterRejecter().catch(ex => console.log('caught ' + ex));
```

Prints `caught rejected` - a simple cascade of the rejection that is obvious.

Comment: You write "The language routes the exception into the err function, and not to the catch function." This is not really confusing if you know that the error handler (second parameter to `then`) is basically the same as the parameter passed to `catch()`. The exception/rejection is already caught before `catch()` is encountered.

Comment: @lex82 is absolutely right about the second function value in the `then` function being the `catch` handler function